# Code behind for event Fire on Mainpage rather than UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an UserControl which has listbox. I put this UserControl on the Mainpage.xaml.  I would like to handl the selected and button click event on Mainpage.xaml.cs rather than on usercontrol.xaml.cs because I will use this UserControl to another page and the respond will be different.  How can I do it? Would you provide example or link to me? Thanks in advance.

There is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMSPhoneApp.QueueListControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMSPhoneApp"  >

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle1" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" BorderBrush="#FF2022BC"/>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    <local:ColumSpanConverter x:Key="ColumSpanConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}" Background="#00E23162">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstCall" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" SelectionChanged="lstCall_SelectionChanged"    >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid  x:Name="grdQueue" Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>                                   
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />                                        
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Type}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan= "{Binding isSpan, Converter={StaticResource ColumSpanConverter}}" Text="{Binding summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                             Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"  />
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" ClickMode="Press" Click="Action_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding isVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Width="85" Height="70" Text="{Binding ActionCaption}" 
                                                       Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle_20}"     />
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>

                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There is the code to add the UserControl on Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <my:QueueListControl />
            </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I am able to bind the data on the lst on MainPage.xaml.cs by the following code:

```
MyQueue = new List<QueueItem>();
        MyQueue.Add(new QueueItem { summary = "Test1tqeewwewew332233 3233322323 wdqwqwqwqwq", status = "Open", callNumber = "1" });
        MyQueue.Add(new QueueItem { summary = "Test1tqeewwewew332233 3233322323 wdqwqwqwqwq", status = "Responded", callNumber = "2" });
        MyQueue.Add(new QueueItem { summary = "Test1tqeewwewew332233 3233322323 wdqwqwqwqwq", status = "Resolved", callNumber = "3" });
        MyQueue.Add(new QueueItem { summary = "Test1tqeewwewew332233 3233322323 wdqwqwqwqwq", status = "transfer", callNumber = "4" });
        MyQueue.Add(new QueueItem { summary = "Test1tqeewwewew332233 3233322323 wdqwqwqwqwq", status = "Complete", callNumber = "5" });
        test.lst.ItemsSource = MyQueue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a library such as [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/); it has a Messenger class ([tutorial](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/)) that you can use to send messages from the UserControl's code behind.

In the MainPage's `OnNavigatedTo` method register for the UserControl's message and in the 'OnNavigatedFrom` method un-register from listening to the message. You can do the same in the other page where you want to use this UserControl.

The message fired by the UserControl must contain all the relevant information needed for either class to react to it appropriately. Thus, you can keep the control's code-behind decoupled from user interaction logic.

Comment: Personally I don't think adding further complexity, via an MVVM framework, is going to help this guy. It is simply a case of creating a proper interface for the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `UserControl` more re-useable by exposing its state and events so that these can be updated / handled by controls that host an instance of your control. See this tutorial for details:

[A Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls in WPF / Silverlight](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/)

Comment: Thanks . I mdoifed my UserControl. However, I still don't know how to do the button Click event on MyMoldeView. Would you point it out or send me the link? Thanks.